# Multi-variate normal distribution covariance matrix

Tags: normal-distribution, multivariate-normal-distribution

Let x ~ *CN* (0,a) and y ~ *CN*(0,b), with a, b positive constants. Let z = x + y. I need to find the distribution of the vector **t**=[x; z]. My basic understanding is that vector **t** is also complex Gaussian distributed and it has  mean [0;0]. I do not know how to compute the covariance matrix of **t**. Can anybody help me? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Because x and y are independent random variables, Var(z) = Var(x) + Var(y) = a + b;

One way to compute the covariance Cov(x,z) = Cov(z,x) is to simply apply the definition of covariance.

Cov(x,z) = E[xz*]-E[x]E[z*], and here we have E[x]=E[z*]=0.

Cov(x,z) = E[x(x+y)* ]=E[xx*+xy*]=E[xx*]+E[xy*]. Note that E[xy*]=E[x]E[y*]=0.

Cov(x,z) = E[xx*].

Observe that Var(x)= E[xx*]-E[x]E[x*] = 1, and E[x]=E[x*]=0 in this exercise.

Finally, Cov(x,y) = a.

Having computed the variances and co variances it is then straightforward to write the correlation matrix.

Comment: These are not the correct definitions for the Complex Normal distribution.  See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_normal_distribution#Mean_and_covariance.

Comment: Isn't it so that I have used the definitions for complex normal variables, while links points to definitions for complex normal vectors? If I understand correctly, x, y and z are complex normal variables, and I compute variance and covariance for normal variables (not vectors). Am I wrong? Thanks

Comment: You are wrong because you neglect to take complex conjugates.

Comment: OK, I see. I try to correct the answer then.